# DropDownListFor`s Selected value works with ViewModel but not integer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

When I select a template in my dropdownlist and press the OK button to make a form post the DeleteTemplateListViewModel object is created and filled with the current templateId and the ModelState is Valid.

When I select the default value "Select a template" in my dropdownlist and press the OK button to make a form post the DeleteTemplateListViewModel object is created and and the ModelState is InValid.

So far so good.

But when I change the Delete action to accept an integer which is the selectedTemplateId the ModelState is Valid for a selected templateId. When I select the default value "Select a template" defined in the DropDownListFor I get in my output window this exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll

How can I make it work with so the ModelState is false/Invalid for the default value using an integer as action parameter instead of a viewModel ?

```
@model ITMS.Web.Models.DeleteTemplateListViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Template"))
{ 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)      
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedTemplateId, 
                               new SelectList(Model.DisplayList, "TemplateId", "Name"),
                               "Select a template", 
                               new { @class = "listviewmodel" })
}


public class DeleteTemplateListViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No template selected.")]
    public int SelectedTemplateId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TemplateViewModel> DisplayList { get; set; }
}
```

**WORKS**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(DeleteTemplateListViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int templateId = viewModel.SelectedTemplateId;
        _templateDataProvider.DeleteTemplate(templateId);
        return new JsonNetResult(new { success = true, templateId = templateId });
    }
    return LoadDeleteTemplates();
}
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int selectedTemplateId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _templateDataProvider.DeleteTemplate(selectedTemplateId);
        return new JsonNetResult(new { success = true, templateId = selectedTemplateId});
    }
    return LoadDeleteTemplates();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, an int can't really get a non-value. Change your Delete method to accept and `int?`.

I don't know what kind of model validation MVC can do an an int? with no additional data, but you should check see if it's null or not.

Comment: Even when I make the integer nullable of the SelectedTemplateId in the View and the action parameter I get Null BUT the Modelstate is true... I wont start with NULL-checks in the controller. This should be handled by validation. As I said before, when I use a viewModel as action parameter it works it just seems overhead to me.

Comment: That's because an int? is not a model. Perhaps you should look into custom validations, or just make a model that contains a single int? property.

Comment: That makes no sense what you say to me. You confuse me. I MADE a int? but it did not help with an int? parameter for the action.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the validation rather in the modelbinding process so maybe I should write a custom model binder?

Comment: I made the SelectedTemplateId and nullable and also the action parameter I made nullable. When I do a httppost and my selecteditem list is empty the SelectedTemplateId action parameter is null BUT the ModelState.IsValid is always TRUE ??? How can I tell the user to select anything ? I do not want to make a null check in the controller...

Comment: Put those into a model. The ModelBinder doesn't work if you don't have a model class.

Comment: Yes it works only with a "model" class not with integer. With a Model and its SelectedTemplateId non-nullable is fine. The ModelState is not valid when the selected item is empty/null. But there is an odd behavior with my initial code in my question. The error message ""No template selected." is not visible. You have any idea?